# Converting SMILES to .sdf files

Tags: cheminformatics

I have around 1000 SMILES entries in Excel and I have to generate `.sdf` file for all. Is there any way to automate this whole process, preferably with an offline tool?

Answer (score 5):

[Datawarrior](http://www.openmolecules.org/datawarrior/) lets you do it.
Export a csv sheet with two columns: The name of the compound and its SMILES code.
Be sure to use a comma as a delimiter.
Your output file, opened with a text editor, should look like this:

```
Name,SMILES
Hexazine,n1nnnnn1
Furazan,c1nonc1
Benzisoxazole,c1noc2c1cccc2
```

From DataWarrior, File>Open and open your file.
Structures are automatically generated from SMILES codes.

Then, File>Save Special>SD-File, and you are done.

Answer (score 4):

Working with this many SMILES you should consider to have a look at [Open Babel](http://openbabel.org/wiki/Main_Page), both, because it may transcribe many chemistry relevant formats as well as extract and filter information from them.  This being said, you have at least two options:

- One time use, preferentially with shorter lists to convert:  Use Open Babel's GUI which equally is freely available.  On the left hand side, select the input format as `.smi` and that you would like to paste the SMILES, rather than to read them from a file. Select on the right hand column the export format and enter the directory where your permanent `.sdf` shall be written.  *Helpful* for a human is to add the option (center column) *"Append output index to title"* as a counter, and *highly recommended* for future work with the `.sdf` to activate *"Generate 3D coordinates"* a bit lower in this column, too.

  [image: Screenshot of the Open Babel GUI]
- Depending on the operational system at your disposition, Open Babel has multiple interfaces to languages like Python.  Let us assume you saved your data in the `.xlsx` format (e.g., Excel, LibreOffice Calc or gnumeric) in the second column of your spreadsheet:

  [image: Screenshot of LibreOffice Calc with partially filled table]

  Even without entering into the inner tools of Open Babel, you then may already benefit from a module like [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to access the SMILES directly, relaying them to Open Babel, e.g.

  ```
  # name:  reader.py

  import openpyxl
  import subprocess as sub
  import sys

  try:
      source_file = sys.argv[1]
      workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(source_file)
      sheet = workbook['Sheet1']
  except:
      print("Call the script on the CLI by 'python reader.py [my_data.xlsx]'.")
      sys.exit()


  def reading():
      """ retrieve the SMILES from the .xlsx """
      global smiles_collector
      smiles_collector = ""
      for cell in sheet['B']:
          smiles_collector += str('-:"') + str(cell.value) + str('" ')


  def writing():
      """ provide a container .sdf """
      reading()
      conversion = str("obabel {} -osdf > output.sdf --gen3d".format(smiles_collector))
      sub.call(conversion, shell=True)


  reading()
  writing()
  sys.exit()
  ```